# How to set expiry time to JWT in php and further check for it (is expired)

Tags: php, angular

I am not able to set an expiry session to jason web token in PHP API.

Comment: kindly explain in greater detail. share your effort with code

Answer (score 1):

The goal of using JWT is so that you can store the expire time within JWT, so the client side can manage `state` which will keep your server `stateless` for scaling purposes.

So when you encrypt or `sign` the JWT just make sure to store expiry time with it, so everytime your user is making a request, put that timer in the header of JWT, and then your server not only will validate the JWT being validate, will also check if it expired or not.

**You should provide some code so we can help more, with what you said there the topic could be pretty broad.**